# Which one is correct `是不是你想离开` or `你是不是想离开`?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence

I think it is correct to say `是不是想离开` to emphasize whether it is true that you want to leave.

I wonder if I want to add `你`, where should it be in the sentence?

`是不是你想离开` or `你是不是想离开`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both 是不是你想离开 and 你是不是想离开 are correct and can mean the same.

However, it's worth to mention that in 是不是你想离开, when you put a tone emphasis on 你 like 是不是'***你***'想离开, it would mean ***Is it you that want to leave***, implying it's you, not others.

Comment: So if I want to use `是不是你想离开` to emphasize `Is it true that you want to leave`, I better put a break between  `是不是` and `你想离开` while speaking? like `是不是,   你想离开`

Comment: @OConnor You can do that but don't have to.  The sentence itself already denotes that sense.

Answer (score 4):

[是不是] [想离开] = [do] (subject omitted) [want to leave?]

[是不是你] [想离开?] = [Is it you who] [want to leave?]

[是不是] [你想离开?] = [Is it] [you want to leave?]

[你是不是] [想离开?] =  [Do you] [want to leave?]

To add the subject '你' to '是不是想离开', It should be placed before the sentence,  是不是想离开, and 你是不是想离开 would have the same meaning. "是不是你想离开?" could change the meaning of "是不是想离开?"

Answer (score 3):

是不是**你**想离开 or **你**是不是想离开, both of them are correct.

You could also say 是不是想離開了**你**？ It's very oral, informal but commonly used by native user.(Taiwan)